# How To Forward-Fill empty values in a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a Big Query table that looks like this:
![Table[(https://ibb.co/1ZXMH71)
As you can see most values are empty.
I'd like to forward-fill those empty values, meaning using the last known value ordered by time.

Apparently, there is a function for that called FILL
https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/FILL-Function_57344752
But I have no idea how to use it.

This is the Query I've tried posting on the web UI:

```
SELECT sns_6,Time
FROM TABLE_PATH
FILL sns_6,-1,0 order: Time
```

the error I get is:
Syntax error: Unexpected identifier "sns_6" at [3:6]
What I want is to get a new table where the column sns_6 is filled with the last known value.

As a bonus: I'd like this to happen for all columns but because fill only supports a single column, for now, I'll have to iterate over all the columns. If anyone has an idea of how to do the iteration This would be a great bonus.

Comment: The `fill()` function is part of Wrangle (https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Wrangle-Language_57344628) not BigQuery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> I'd like to forward-fill those empty values, meaning using the last known value ordered by time

```
#standardSQL
SELECT time
  LAST_VALUE(sns_1 IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY time) sns_1,
  LAST_VALUE(sns_2 IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY time) sns_2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

> I'd like this to happen for all columns

You can add as many below lines as many columns you need to fill (obviously you need to replace `sns_N` with the real column's name

```
  LAST_VALUE(sns_N IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY time) sns_N
```

Comment: Thank you that actually worked and was much simpler than what I've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your screen shot has to do with your query.

I think this will do what you want:

```
SELECT sns_6, Time,
       LAST_VALUE(sns_6 IGNORE NULLS) ORDER BY (Time) as imputed_sns_6
FROM TABLE_PATH;
```

EDIT:

This query works fine when I run it:

```
select table_path.*, last_value(sn_6 ignore nulls) over (order by time)
from (select 1 as time, null as sn_6 union all
      select 2, 1 union all
      select 3, null union all
      select 4, null union all
      select 5, null union all
      select 6, 0 union all
      select 7, null union all
      select 8, null
     ) table_path;
```

Comment: I've tried that query and got the following error:Syntax error: Unexpected keyword AS at [2:48]
also what do you mean by imputed_sns_6?

Comment: @DanielZiv . . . the query works fine when I run it.  Are you sure you are using Standard SQL?