# Bigquery equivalent for pandas fillna(method='ffill')

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

I have a BQ db of around 121M rows and loading it in pandas doesn't scale. I'm looking to forward fill columns in a group (based on certain column values) that are null.

How can this be achieved in BQ? Can it be done in DataPrep?

Comment: example of input and desired output along with filling logic will make your question an answerable question :o)

Comment: This question was answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56314774/how-to-forward-fill-empty-values-in-a-table